# Javascript bookmarket unexpected identifier?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

It would be hugely appreciated if you could just run through this code and see if you spot an **"unexpected identifier"**. Thanks so much guys.

`javascript:(function () {
    url = document.location.href;
    if (url.match('youtube.com/watch?')) {
        var s=document.createElement('script');
        s.setAttribute('src','http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js');
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
        dataString = 'url=' url;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/create/',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data){ console.log(data); }
        });
    }
    else {
        alert('This is not a youtube video.')
    }
    })();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
dataString = 'url=' url;
```

Should be:

```
dataString = 'url=' + url;
```

Mind you, you can avoid awkward string concats by giving `$.ajax` an object to work with - especially useful if the number of params increases:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {url: url}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You assignment of dataString is not concatenating properly:

```
dataString = 'url=' url;
```

should be:

```
dataString = 'url=' + url;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be different....

```
dataString = 'url='.concat(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be more different...

```
dataString = 'url=' url;
```

should be:

```
var urleq = 'url=',
    dataString = [urleq, eval(urleq.substr(0,urleq.length-1))].join('');
```